# Detect if new keyboard is added

Tags: android

I am creating a custom keyboard and I want to detect if keyboard is currently enabled and perform action immediately.

```
Boolean x  = checkIfKeyboardIsSelected();


private Boolean checkIfKeyboardIsSelected() {
    Intent enableIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS);
    enableIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    getActivity().startActivity(enableIntent);

    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    String list = imm.getEnabledInputMethodList().toString();

    Log.e("List", list);

    if(list.contains(KEYBOARDID))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

But the string doesn't contain the keyboard ID even though the user selects one. Is there a way to detect if the user selects one? Broadcast receiver or anything else?

Comment: isn't your list empty ?

Comment: no. It has the string of all enabled keyboard. But, I want to detect the keyboard after the user selects one.

Comment: where did this "KEYBOARDID" come from?

Comment: This is my keyboardID, it has ID with my keyboard name.